# Use generator to do inorder traversal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, generator

I am not used to generators and wonder how to make code cleaner/Pythonic in the generator part.

The function is about validating a binary search tree. The `inorder_gen` function yield one element a time. The main function compares the value yielded and previous yielded value to determine whether BST's invariant is violated.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):

    def isValidBST(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        last_val = None
        for idx, v in enumerate(self.inorder_gen(root)):
            if idx != 0 and v <= last_val:
                return False
            last_val = v
        return True

    def inorder_gen(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return 
        if node.left != None:
            for v in self.inorder_gen(node.left):
                yield v
        yield node.val
        if node.right != None:
            for v in self.inorder_gen(node.right):
                yield v
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your structure seems adequate, but there are a couple of mistakes, and some new language syntax in 3.3 that will make things even clearer:

1. That name!

   ```
   def inorder_gen(self, node):
   ```

   The name does make it obvious what order you're using. And it also explains that you're writing a generator - which is putting implementation details in the public interface. Don't do that. You could go with `inorder()`, but even better would be to make your class iterable using the standard Python approach. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator#24377) for an example of how.
2. You were off to a good start ...

   ```
   if node is None:
       return 
   if node.left != None:
   ```

   ... but then you tried to use `!= None`. Use `is None` or `is not None` instead. (Like you did on the first line!)
3. Use Python's [`yield from` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) to connect a nested generator to your caller. This code:

   ```
   if node.left != None:
       for v in self.inorder_gen(node.left):
           yield v
   yield node.val
   if node.right != None:
       for v in self.inorder_gen(node.right):
           yield v
   ```

   Becomes this:

   ```
   yield from self.inorder_gen(node.left) if node.left is not None else ()
   yield node.val
   yield from self.inorder_gen(node.right) if node.right is not None else ()
   ```

   And if your nodes default to truthy (which most objects do), you can replace `if node.left is not None` with `if node.left`, for more readability!

   ```
   yield from self.inorder_gen(node.left) if node.left else ()
   yield node.val
   yield from self.inorder_gen(node.right) if node.right else ()
   ```
4. **Bonus:** If you make your TreeNode class iterable, as mentioned in #1, and you use `yield from` as mentioned in #3, you can make your code even smaller! Since the nodes are iterable, and since `yield from` will accept an iterable, you can yield from the nodes directly, like this:

   ```
   # NOTE: This has to be on the node class, so if you can't change 
   # that, it won't work. (But maybe you could subclass the TreeNode?)

   def __iter__(self):
       if self.left: yield from self.left
       yield self.val
       if self.right: yield from self.right
   ```

   (In fairness, this last example came from the PEP proposing the `yield from` syntax: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/yield-from/yf_current/Examples/binary_tree.py, and see overview page here: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/yield-from/yield_from.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments! Appreciate it and learned a lot.

Comment: Great suggestions. I don't understand the *"and if your nodes default to truthy..."* remark, when would a node in a tree not be truthy (except for the case of a completely empty tree, where the root node itself is `None`)? (we're inspecting its id, right?, not its value).

Comment: @smci Python gives you the ability to override things like that using the dundermethods. Normally, you wouldn't do this, but occasionally someone must use those methods, right?

Comment: @aghast: That isn't an answer, though. I'm simply seeking confirmation that the only case in an n-ary tree where an actual node itself could be `None` (as opposed to its children), is the base-case of an empty tree. Correct? If not, what's another example?

Comment: @smci: If your `.left` or `.right` value is `None`, then the expression will evaluate to `False.` According to [the docs,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) *"By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a __bool__() method that returns False or a __len__() method that returns zero, when called with the object."* So by default, an instance of whatever class that is not `None` but an actual object will *probably* evaluate as truthy.

Comment: @aghast: I already said that and I said I'm not talking about the `if self.left:`or `.right`. Ok you're referring to what are truthy values in `yield self.val`.